# On Android 12, the extension of the file is cut with long file names

Tags: android, android-12

On Android 12, Issue reproducible with long file names. As it can see in the images attached, the extension of the file is cut in portrait.

The question is: when showing a file name in one line, and android:ellipsize="middle" is required, the suffix of the file name is not displayed completely when setsetting "android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"

and the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_line_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth="true"
        android:text="RF_20210819NZ Herald - Breaking news, latest news, business, sport and entertainment - NZ Herald.url"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="RF_20210819NZ Herald - Breaking news, latest news, business, sport and entertainment - NZ Herald.url" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_line_text" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrLJE.png)

Comment: I couldn't understand a thing

Comment: Uh, yes - truncating a long string with an ellipses ("...") is a *feature*.  Which you've specified with `android:ellipsize="middle"`.  Q: What exactly is your question?  That the rightmost edge seems to be truncated?

Comment: The question is: 
when showing a file name in one line, and android:ellipsize="middle" is required,
the suffix of the file name is not displayed completely

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:maxLines="1"`. It makes the text stay on one line. That is if you were trying to move the text to a second line. and remove `android:ellipsize="middle"`, makes the declared `android:maxline="1"`, which actually makes the text stay on one line to be truncated in the middle.

And I also think you don't need `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`, Because you set the TextView's width to `match_contraint` already, by setting it to 0

`tools:text="..."` is used for testing your UI, to see how it works with different lengths of text and so on. You don't need to put both `android:text="..."` and `tools:text="..."` together.

Comment: The question is: 
when showing a file name in one line, and android:ellipsize="middle" is required,
the suffix of the file name is not displayed completely